# SOAP API ExtractRequest FTP Location

Tags: marketing-cloud

Running an Extract Request, is it possible to change the FTP location where the file is dropped? We want to put the file in a different folder on the enhanced FTP if possible. By the docs is sounds possible but I cannot find a code example or the parameter names.

https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/methods/extract/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no. There is no way to specify a different folder during the file transfer. You can specify a different ftp location, however sub folders are also not accepted there either.

You will basically always be locked into the root folder. In the enhanced ftp location it will depend on the upload/download selection.

#### Extract SOAP Packet

```
  <ExtractRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
     <Requests>
        <ID>bb94a04d-9632-4623-be47-daabc3f588a6</ID>
        <Parameters>
           <Parameter>
              <Name>DECustomerKey</Name>
              <Value>OrderHistory</Value>
           </Parameter>
           <Parameter>
              <Name>HasColumnHeaders</Name>
              <Value>true</Value>
           </Parameter>
           <Parameter>
              <!--This parameter is required, always pass a value of 0-->
              <Name>_AsyncID</Name>
              <Value>0</Value>
           </Parameter>
           <Parameter>
              <Name>OutputFileName</Name>
              <Value>MyExtractFile.csv</Value>
           </Parameter>
           <Parameter>
              <!--This parameter is required, always pass value shown below-->
              <Name>StartDate</Name>
              <Value>1/1/1900 1:00:00 AM</Value>
           </Parameter>
           <Parameter>
              <!--This parameter is required, always pass value shown below-->
              <Name>EndDate</Name>
              <Value>1/1/1900 1:00:00 AM</Value>
           </Parameter>
        </Parameters>
     </Requests>
  </ExtractRequestMsg>
```

#### File Transfer

```
  <PerformRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
   <Options/>
   <Action>Start</Action>
   <Definitions>
    <ns1:Definition xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="ns1:FileTransferActivity">
     <ns1:ModifiedDate xsi:nil="true"/>
     <ns1:ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
     <ns1:CustomerKey>12345</ns1:CustomerKey>
    </ns1:Definition>
   </Definitions>
  </PerformRequestMsg>
```

Comment: Thanks. Are you able to provide an example, or direct me to where I can get the info on the nodes I need to add to my SOAP env? I couldn't find anything online.

Comment: Not sure what you are after specifically.

Comment: In the example SOAP request on https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/methods/extract/ it doesn't show how to specify a different FTP location. I am wondering how I would update that XML to specify a different location.

Comment: You would have to perform a `FileTransferActivity` to the FTP location after performing the Extract.  Extract pulls the data, and sends to a staging location.  Once that's done. You would transfer the file.  Typically these are done as an Automation, performing the transfer upon extract completion.